# I am trying to make a Polynomial regression line with data from CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, linear-regression, polynomials

My code is running but will not give any output whatsoever and I am not sure why? 
[Here is a picture of the file phillies_of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLsyq.png)

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

#national league east
phillies_of = pd.read_csv('/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/Teams/PHILLIES.csv', header = None)
phillies_pr = pd.read_csv('/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/Teams/PHILLIES_PR.csv',header = None)

X = phillies_of.iloc[1:33, [5, 9, 10, 13, 17, 18, 21, 23, 25]].values
Y = phillies_of.iloc[1:33,2].values

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 8)
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X)

print('Done')

poly.fit(X_poly, Y)
lin2 = LinearRegression()
lin2.fit(X_poly, Y)

print('Done 2.0')

plt.scatter(X, Y, color = 'blue', s = 10)
plt.plot(X, lin2,predict(poly.fit_transform(X)), color = 'red')
plt.show()

lin2.predict(poly.fit_transform(110.0))
```

Output: 
Done

Comment: There are three lines of code between "Done" and "Done 2.0". If you comment them out then both print statements should run. You can then comment in each line, one at a time.

Comment: @JamesPhillips this the error message I get once I do that:                    
ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Comment: Did both "Done" and "Done 2.0" print before the error?

Comment: Could you provide some rows from both of your CSV files as text into your question (use the [edit] button to update it). We would then be able to copy/paste it (rather than typing it all in from a picture). i.e. just enough to recreate the problem, the full data set is not needed.

Comment: @MartinEvans I provide a picture of the file in the link above

Comment: In order to test your code, I would have to type all of that data in manually. I don't wish to do that, pasting as text allows it to be copy/pasted.